# Updating global variables

Tags: c, linked-list, global-variables

I'm inserting words into the beginning of a `LinkedList`, and am using head and next global variables to do so.

For example:

```
Node *head; 
Node *nextNode;
....

Node *newNode;
newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node)); 

if(newNode != NULL)
{
        newNode->item = strdup(new_string); 
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;

        nextNode = head->next;
}
```

Changing the head variable is correct, although I'm unsure if you can simply set `nextNode` to where head points next. (I think that you have to assign it similarly as how I did with the head variable.) Does anyone have any explanation as to how I can continually update the `nextNode` variable?

EDIT:
The reason I'm keeping track of both a head and a next node is because I'm creating a traversal method, that when called, will give the current item in the node. For example;

```
char* nextItem()
{
    char* nextWord = NULL;

    if(nextNode != NULL)
    {
        nextNode = nextNode->next;

        nextWord = nextNode->item;
    }

    return nextWord;
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. You've already added the `newNode` to the beginning of the list. What is the purpose of `nextNode`? We can't tell you how to set it if you don't tell us what the requirement is.

Comment: you don't have to use `Node *nextNode;` at all, you don't need it

Comment: @user180708 That is clearer but still not fully clear. It seems you are using `nextNode` as an iterator. Putting aside that this isn't really a good idea (a global iterator only allows one iteration operation at a time) we still can't tell you what to do. You need to define what `nextNode` should point to when a new item is added - it's up to you. So if you want it to point to the `head` then do that. If you want it to not change then do that. etc. Without the actual requirement (defined by you) there's not much to say.